# Displaying a custom div inline with a h5

Tags: html, css

I know it sounds simple, but this is really annoying me. I have researched online and not found a perfect answer for me yet.

I have this html code:

```
<h5 class="start-online"><div id="online_ajax">0</div> Clients online </h5>
```

I want the online_ajax div to display inline before the Client online text.

My current css is:

```
h5.start-online {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.online_ajax {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You cannot nest `<div>` inside `<h5>`. **Period.** Make it `span` instead.

Comment: Oh. Is there a way I can make them side by side and still keep my concept of making the div before a h5 but on the same line ?

Comment: Your markup is invalid, just as Praveen said, also, you are using an `id` which needs to be selected using `#` and not `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot nest `<div>` inside `<h5>`. **Period.** Make it `<span>` instead.

```
<h5 class="start-online"><span id="online_ajax">0</span> Clients online </h5>
```

You don't even need to style it! The `<span>` tag is the inline version of `<div>` tag (as how `<div>` tag is the inline version of `<span>`).

Also, in your CSS, you are supposed to select the `id` and `#` is the ID selector.

```css
#online_ajax {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

But yeah, as I said you before, please don't use `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake.

`online_ajax` is an id, use `#` instead of `dot(.)`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before: You should use `<span>` instead of `<div>`. Then you don't need `display: inline-block;` anymore in your css.